# Creating Custom Logger for Both .Net core and WCF

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working  with micro services some of my micro services are written in WCF,and rest are Asp.net core,Now i would like to maintain a centralized logger system among those micro services.So that i want to create common custom logger which inherit ILogger. Is there any way to create a common logger library which will support both WCF and Asp.net core API ?

Comment: I don't understand what part you're stuck on? Can you explain what's preventing you from accomplishing your task?

Answer (score 0):

Do you ask which framework can you use? Ff yes then you can write a library in standard and use that. The purpose of .NET Standard is simple: to share code between runtimes. When you want to share code between different runtimes in the .NET Ecosystem, use .NET Standard.[1]
 [1] https://stackify.com/net-standard-explained/ 

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard